# Factory pattern, initialization parameters

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, factory, factory-pattern

I am reading Hodges book "More Coding in Delphi", section on Factory Pattern. I come up with a problem. I need to implement Init procedures for each descendant of `TBaseGateway` class. The problem is I do not know how to pass correct record type. Is there any nice solution?

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Generics.Collections, System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Dialogs;

type
  TGatewayTpe = (gtSwedbank, gtDNB);

type
  IGateway = interface
    ['{07472665-54F5-4868-B4A7-D68134B9770B}']
    procedure Send(const AFilesToSend: TStringList);
  end;

type
  TBaseGateway = class(TAggregatedObject, IGateway)
  public
    procedure Send(const AFilesToSend: TStringList); virtual; abstract;
  end;

type
  TSwedbankGateway = class(TBaseGateway)
  public
    // procedure Init(const ASwedbanRecord: TSwedBankRecord);
    procedure Send(const AFilesToSend: TStringList); override;
  end;

type
  TDNBGateway = class(TBaseGateway)
  public
    // procedure Init(const ADNBRecord: TDNBRecord);
    procedure Send(const AFilesToSend: TStringList); override;
  end;

type
  TGatewayFunction = reference to function: TBaseGateway;

type
  TGatewayTypeAndFunction = record
    GatewayType: TGatewayTpe;
    GatewayFunction: TGatewayFunction;
  end;

type
  TGatewayFactory = class
  strict private
    class var FGatewayTypeAndFunctionList: TList<TGatewayTypeAndFunction>;
  public
    class constructor Create;
    class destructor Destroy;
    class procedure AddGateway(const AGatewayType: TGatewayTpe;
      const AGatewayFunction: TGatewayFunction);
  end;

implementation

class procedure TGatewayFactory.AddGateway(const AGatewayType: TGatewayTpe;
  const AGatewayFunction: TGatewayFunction);

var
  _GatewayTypeAndFunction: TGatewayTypeAndFunction;
begin
  _GatewayTypeAndFunction.GatewayType := AGatewayType;
  _GatewayTypeAndFunction.GatewayFunction := AGatewayFunction;

  FGatewayTypeAndFunctionList.Add(_GatewayTypeAndFunction);
end;

class constructor TGatewayFactory.Create;
begin
  FGatewayTypeAndFunctionList := TList<TGatewayTypeAndFunction>.Create;
end;

class destructor TGatewayFactory.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FGatewayTypeAndFunctionList);
end;

procedure TSwedbankGateway.Send(const AFilesToSend: TStringList);
begin
  ShowMessage(Self.ClassName);
end;

procedure TDNBGateway.Send(const AFilesToSend: TStringList);
begin
  ShowMessage(Self.ClassName);
end;

initialization

TGatewayFactory.AddGateway(gtDNB,
 function: TBaseGateway
  begin
    Result := TDNBGateway.Create(nil);
  end);

TGatewayFactory.AddGateway(gtSwedbank,
  function: TBaseGateway
  begin
    Result := TSwedbankGateway.Create(nil);
  end);

end.
```

Comment: So you want your gateways created with a factory to init automatically? Then, to answer your question, we need to understand, where our factory should take ADNBRecord or ASwedbanRecord, is it the same every time we create instances or passed to factory? If it's the first case, you could init each class properly in anonymous function you pass as argument (create, as you wrote, and then Init with proper argument). In the second case, question arises: what is point of factory if by calling it with one or another type of argument you in fact wait predefined class to arise?

Comment: "in the first case" i'd make some general configuration service, and made gateways to fetch their configurations from it when being creating. If configuration might be changed on-the-go, without application restart, then the configuration service should also track timestamps of configuration sections change, so that gateways' `.Send` functions could check whether config changed since last initialization and then re-initialize itself if needed